# how to change the IMEI of a generic ANDROID cellphone

Tags: root-access, rom, twrp, imei

First of all,

I live in Brazil, and my country still deny the entrance of generic cellphones from China, the politicians here want to receive more tax from buying a original cellphone at a price of an Apple top line.

Then I buy a generic cellphone.

The problem is, the IMEI isn't into the Federal database of cellphones, this alarm the services providers to troll me with a low traffic bandwidth, unable to call, and when I can do a call this goes down after some minuter (not more than 3).

I think the only way to bypass this protection is copy an IMEI from a digitally assigned device, the Federal lawyer in communications called ANATEL.

Well, I rooted my cellphone, I don't know the techniques to place a new IMEI on it, but, i find these files http://pastebin.com/bgBybbnL. I think the IMEI comes with a private key to ciphers the communication, then, how can I get this informations?

Thanks guy! u will help me a lot if you can answer!

Comment: The method to change the IMEI varies for different devices.. What is your device name or model?

Comment: As you already have a rooted phone, you can use **Xprivacy** which is a very powerful tool to spoof **mobile identifiers**. Xprivacy is required xposed framework to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've xposed framework installed, you may be able to change by installing [This module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.phoneinfo.changer). I've tried changing IMEI with module and it worked.

Comment: I assume that "it worked" means that you see the modified IMEI in every app/settings on your device. However this does not necessarily means that the modified IMEI is used when you do a call. The network connection is established by a separate sub-module which can not be modified with Xposed. Therefore I doubt that the modified IMEI is used when communicating with the cell tower.

Comment: I checked by *#06#. OP can give it a try and comment. If he's still blocked in Brazil that means it didn't work.